# Get field values in Runtime

Tags: java, reflection, runtime, field

How to get value of the field in Runtime for Java?

**EDIT:**

using this construction:

```
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
 new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(
                    false);
        for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner
        .findCandidateComponents("aspectlogging"))
                        {
            Class myTarget = null;
                try {
                        myTarget = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
                     }
                       catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {...}
                for (Field f:myTarget.getDeclaredFields()){
                        try {
                            System.out.println("FIELD: " + f.get(myTarget));
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {...} 
                              catch (IllegalAccessException e) {...}
                    } }
```

I've got `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`,
 when call `f.get(myTarget)`,
 where  `myTarget` is the instance of bean got in Runtime and `f` is its field.

when run in loop following:

```
System.out.println("FIELD: " + f);
```

got field names OK:

```
FIELD: private java.lang.String aspectlogging.TestableBean.name
FIELD: private java.lang.String aspectlogging.TestableBean.name
```

It's quite strange,that value can't be got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arg` ([called `obj` in the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getInt%28java.lang.Object%29)) is the instance on which to operate. In your example, the instance is `bd`, so use `f.getInt(bd)` to extract an `int` field and so on.

Comment: aix, see,please,my edited post, I still can't get value of field.Fields of bean where got OK,but when try get values exception thrown.